# Using 'anyone' in affirmative contexts - Is "he just wanted to kill anyone" grammatical?

Tags: pronouns, polarity-items

I've just stumbled across [this article in the Japan Times](http://www.japantimes.co.jp/news/2014/10/17/national/crime-legal/student-held-for-stabbing-woman-wanted-to-kill-anyone/#.VEE5yXWUe00):

> SAITAMA – Police, who are interrogating a 20-year-old college student from Saitama Prefecture on suspicion of stabbing to death a 21-year-old woman in the city of Iruma, in the same prefecture, revealed Friday that the suspect said that he “**just wanted to kill anyone**.”

And I'm wondering if "wanted to kill anyone" is correct (I'm not a native speaker, but "anyone" in place of "someone" feels odd to me).

Comment: There is a word "anyone" that tends to be more commonly found in negative or non-affirmative environments. So that issue could be related, maybe. And that might be why the excerpt sounds a bit unusual to us. In any case, since the stuff is within a quote, er, well, that's the way it is.

Answer (score 7):

Without further context, a native speaker would also expect "wanted to kill someone", rather than "wanted to kill anyone".

The article also quotes the confessed killer as saying "I was thinking about killing someone".

"wanted to kill anyone" is grammatically correct.  In this example, the difference between "someone" and "anyone" might be the result of poor translation, or it might reflect a difference in meaning.  "Someone" implies that the perpetrator was being slightly choosier than if he sought "to kill anyone".

In my opinion, the article has excellent translation.  Most Japanese crime stories (that I have read in English) have much worse translations.

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that if we consider the direct speech version, *("I wanted to kill **anyone**")*, the actual word "anyone" would normally be heavily stressed. This emphasises that the speaker doesn't care at all *which particular person he might kill*. Without that stress, "someone" would be more likely, but the emphasis would then fall on the verb ***kill***, rather than *someone/anyone*.

Answer (score 6):

In context, the writer is trying to make the point that this person didn't care who he killed, it wasn't that he believed his victim had wronged him in some way and he was trying to get revenge or some such. He just wanted to pick a random person and kill them. So if the writer had said, "He wanted to kill someone", that could be understood to mean a specific someone, this particular person. But "he wanted to kill anyone" makes clear that he didn't care who he killed.

It's an unusual phrasing, but then, the desire to kill a random person for no apparent reason is an unusual event. At least, I hope so.

Comment: +1 "It's an unusual phrasing"- What would a native writer of English write assuming he had the same message the Japanese writer wanted to convey?

Comment: @learner- It's a snippet of reported speech which is why it's in quotes. So a native writer of English has little to do with it.

Comment: @learner What they actually said was [「殺すのは誰でもよかった」](http://www.asahi.com/articles/ASGBJ349KGBJUTNB002.html).  Loosely translated: "I just wanted to kill someone.  I didn't care who."

Comment: @learner: If one were not trying to imply direct quotation, a reasonable phrasing might be "He was just interested in killing," or perhaps "He just wanted to kill some arbitrary person".

Comment: The fact that it's a hopefully-unusual situation (just wanting to kill someone) doesn't mean that using an unusual expression (just want to kill anyone) is warranted.  In English, the phrase "He just wanted to kill someone" is already clear that he didn't have anyone in particular in mind.   "He just wanted to kill anyone" is not a phrase to advise ELL readers to use.

Comment: "He just wanted to kill someone" could be understood that he had a particular person in mind. This conversation is easy to imagine: "He just wanted to kill someone." "Oh? Who?" "Sally Jones." That is, "someone" does not necessarily mean any random person; it can simply mean an unidentified person. If I call a company's customer service department and say, "I gave my payment to someone at your office last week", I surely don't mean that I gave it to any random person I found wandering around the building. I just don't know the person's name.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase "just wanted to kill anyone" does sound odd to a native speaker if the intonation is exactly the same as "just wanted to kill someone," which would involve relatively even stress.  If the stress is placed on "anyone," as in "just wanted to kill *anyone*," then it would be correct and immediately comprehensible to a native speaker.  Even so, it's not a particularly desirable translation.  The emphasis on "anyone" shifts the meaning to "anyone at all, as opposed to someone in particular."

[Edit 1: this is a very fine point] Oddly, something of the same effect happens if you put the stress on "someone."  If the suspect said he "just wanted to kill *someone*," it would suggest that he wanted to kill someone, as opposed to killing no one, in which case it also wouldn't make that much difference who the someone was.

Ah English.  Gotta love it!  Unless you hate it.

Comment: Was gonna love English too if it wasn't for the last twist "*it would suggest that he wanted to kill someone, as opposed to killing no one, in which case it also wouldn't make that much difference who the someone was.*"! I'm sorry but I think you may have lost me there a little bit. I thought you were going to say "*it would suggest that he wanted to kill someone* (specific in mind)"; think of "*someone is going to die*" alluding to someone present as you speak. What do you think of these two mentioned scenarios? +1!

Comment: Sorry, @learner, I think I may have gotten too caught up in a fine point.  I considered a long edit of the post, contrasting "someone is going to die" with "_someone_ is going to die."  Then I started to get caught up in the suspect saying he "just wanted to kill someone" as opposed to saying he "wanted to kill someone," i.e. what the word "just" does there.  Then I gave up.  Oh well.  :-(

Comment: I think the word just did the trick. I don't know or remember whether you mentioned before but the point is I think I get it now, thanks.